# PHP, mySQL, line breaks, and textareas

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, newline

I have a textarea. User inputs text into the textarea, which can contain line breaks for formatting purposes.  I save this text to the mySQL database as is without adding HTML br breaks.  This looks like "text blah blah.\n\nText2 blah blah." in the database record.

I display the text on a regular HTML page using `echo nl2br($text);` and the text is nicely formatted, with two line breaks showing up as a two sentences with a blank line between them.

When I send the same text to a textarea prepopulated for the user to edit their original entry, I use the following code:

`<textarea><?php echo $text;?></textarea>`

I expect that I would get a textarea filled with text that includes some double line breaks as are stored in the database.  I don't use nl2br in this case, because doing so would just literally show the HTML characters (not actually create line breaks -- in other words display to the user the 6 characters of the br).  Instead, what I get is stripping of any double new lines, so that two new lines back-to-back are now single new lines.  The single new lines don't get stripped out completely -- they just stay single new lines.

So, in short, when I send text with formatting that should include a blank line between lines of text, what I get is only single new lines, breaking the important formatting of the text).

How can I preserve all of the newlines when outputting text from the database to a textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$txt = "line1\nline2\n\nline4\nline5";
?>
<html>

<body>

<form>
<textarea rows=10><?php echo $txt ?></textarea>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Note the lack of `line3` text and the double `\n\n`. Loading this form in Firefox gives me a blank line between the line2/line4 text, as expected.

Check that your text isn't being mangled elsewhere, and really is in the database as a double-line break.

Comment: Now I'm a bit mistified... I copied your code directly into mine (skipping the db altogether), and I got 4 lines of text with no blank line 3.  I looked at the CSS and white-space property is not defined by me (browser default is white-space: pre-wrap; and looks the same in IE and Chrome) -- could this be the problem?

Comment: Also tried in FF - same story, and tried changing the css properties of white-space.  The output is definitely without two linebreaks despite \n\n -- could a PHP setting be the culprit?

Comment: Confirmed that your code works as is -- something must be modifying my HTML after it is loaded to the text box... time to sift through the JS and see if anything is getting removed...

Answer (score 1):

You can try ...  echo str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $txt)

This simple reads the line breaks and converts them in new rows which are clearly understood by textareas :) hope this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after some troubleshoot my findings is as follows:

All textareas show \n\n with line breaks no matter if value if coming from db, session or cookie.

But if HTML page is MINIFIED the empty lines disappear as final HTML was minified. Means in favour of reducing page size whitespaces are cleaned from document.

Checking actual HTML would proove this.

I use my OWN minify function with Output buffer so I just included one exception for that page.

=> I mean do not monify the page holding the important textarea!

The PHP code in header, would be something like this:

```
$minify_exceptions = array(
    "page1.php",
    "page2.php"
);
if (isset($file_route) && in_array($file_route, $minify_exceptions)) {
    ob_start();
} else {
    ob_start("minify_html");
}
```

NOTE:
This code alone does nothing.If you have any 3rd party HTML minifier, or HTML piped via another server e.g. Google Page Speed you need to find an exceptions list for pages somewhere (where MINIFY happens)

P.S. Smarter way would be to enhance your MINIFY function not to MINIFY text between textarea tags